# JToolTip text with images

Tags: java, html, jtooltip

I want my `JToolTip` object to display text with some pictures in it. I use the following construction:

```
JToolTip t = new JToolTip();
t.setTipText("<html>1st text <img src=\"file:sample.png\"> 2nd text");
```

It works well when file `sample.png` is located in the root directory. But it  doesn't work of course if `sample.png` is packed into .jar file. Is it possible to make program "see" the file even if it is packed in .jar?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly my queston. Thank you so much.

Comment: NP ~ Glad to help :)